# How to add a Multi Checkbox List to the editor of a Form-based Element?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I'm trying to build a custom [Typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) Form Element. I have predefined multiple datasets to draw autocomplete suggestions from. When users add my field to a form, I want them to be able to select one or more of these datasets through checkboxes.

Orchard does not seem to have any Shape like this out of the box. By looking at other Form Elements in `Orchard.DynamicForms` and the SelectList Shape defined in `Orchard.Forms.Shapes.EditorShapes.cs`, I was able to piece together this working code for the Driver:

```
public class TypeaheadFieldElementDriver : FormsElementDriver<TypeaheadField> {
    private readonly ITokenizer _tokenizer;
    private readonly IEnumerable<IDataSet> _dataSets;
    public TypeaheadFieldElementDriver(IFormsBasedElementServices formsServices, ITokenizer tokenizer, IEnumerable<IDataSet> _dataSets)
        : base(formsServices)
    {
        _tokenizer = tokenizer;
        this._dataSets = _dataSets;
    }

    ...

    protected override void DescribeForm(DescribeContext context) {
        context.Form("TypeaheadField", factory =>
        {
            var shape = (dynamic)factory;
            var form = shape.Fieldset(
                Id: "TypeaheadField",
                _Value: shape.Textbox(
                    Id: "Value",
                    Name: "Value",
                    Title: "Value",
                    Classes: new[] { "text", "medium", "tokenized" },
                    Description: T("The value of this typeahead field.")),
               _DataSetIds: shape.SelectList(
                    Id: "DataSetIds",
                    Name: "DataSetIds",
                    Title: "Remote Datasets",
                    Multiple: true,
                    Description: T("The remote datasets to fetch suggestions from.")));

            foreach (var dataSet in _dataSets)
            {
                form._DataSetIds.Items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = T(dataSet.Description).Text, Value = dataSet.Id });
            }

            return form;
        });

        ...
    }
}
```

This successfully renders a multiple select field and sort of works for my purposes but I'm not able to completely unselect every option because the one that was selected keeps getting posted. For this reason and just general ease of use, I would prefer to render a list of checkboxes instead but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing to me as you write Typeahead and then you write multi-select list or checkbox list. I don't know of a multi-select or checkbox option in Typeahead. Btw i recommend using https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js instead of the official typeahead repo which because its basically dead.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Thanks for the suggestion. I'm sorry if I formulated the question poorly. None of my question is actually really related to the Typeahead itself. My intention is for the users who add the field to their form to be able to check multiple sources that they want to use for autocomplete suggestions (which are defined by classes that implement an IDataSet interface I created). So I need a way to dynamically render a list of options in the editor and retrieve all selected values as a collection.